# How can I to download a QR Code to user device using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, download, qr-code

I have a app that shows a QR Code that stores a simple string, using the qr_flutter package.
But beyond showing the QR Code, I want that when user taps a button, a image of that QR Code is downloaded to device too.
I have searched and didn't find any package that can make this.

Comment: You might want to explain for each platform what does `a image of that QR Code is downloaded to device too` means. If you mean "to share" that is also a nuanced question (but various plug-ins exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did recently using [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) plugin with [pretty_qr_code](https://pub.dev/packages/pretty_qr_code)

```
ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

Screenshot(
  controller: screenshotController,
  child: PrettyQr(
    image:AssetImage(AppConfig.placeholder),
    typeNumber: 4,
    size: 300,
    elementColor: Color(0xff596DFF),
    data: invitationCode,
    errorCorrectLevel: QrErrorCorrectLevel.Q,
    roundEdges: false
  ),
)


Future<void> _captureAndSharePng() async {
  screenshotController.capture().then((File image1) async {
    //Capture Done
    List<int> bytes1 = await image1.readAsBytes();

    await Share.file("Code",
      'title' + ".jpg", bytes1, 'image/jpg',
      text: "Join Group by scanning this code"
    );
  }).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
  });
}
```

Share image using [esys_flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share)